# Sort Array Alphanumerically Swift3

Tags: ios, arrays, sorting, swift3

I have a function I was using in Xcode 8 Beta, which sorted an array alphabetically then numerically.

The function I used was:

```
func sortArray(arrayToSort: [String])->[String]{

let sortedArray = arrayToSort.sorted {
(first, second) in
first.compare(second, options: .numericSearch) == ComparisonResult.orderedAscending
}
   print(sortedArray)
   return sortedArray
}
```

However this doesnt work anymore. Does anyone had any idea how I can do this in Swift 3?

Answer (score 1):

There is a function [sort()](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/unsafemutablebufferpointer/1687621-sort) through which you can sort your array like this

```
var arrSort = ["Rajat", "Test", "Sort", "Array","2","6"]
arrSort.sort()
print(arrSort)
```

Answer (score 1):

After some further digging I found an answer:

```
let myArray = ["Step 6", "Step 12", "Step 10"]

let sortedArray = myArray.sorted {
$0.compare($1, options: .numeric) == .orderedAscending
}

print(sortedArray) // ["Step 6", "Step 10", "Step 12"]
```

This was based on Martin R, and Duncan C's posts.

Thank You! ^_______^

Answer (score 0):

You can try this example as below:

```
func sortArray(arrayToSort: [String])->[String] {
   let sortedArray = arrayToSort.sorted(by:) {
     (first, second) in
     first.compare(second, options: .numeric) == ComparisonResult.orderedAscending
   }
   print(sortedArray)
   return sortedArray
}
```